# jquery .each waiting for function to finish before continuing through loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm essentially trying to loop through a collection of LI tags and insert some text to simulate the look of someone writing a list of things to do.  It works, but it writes each of the list items simultaneously instead of waiting.  Is there an easy way to achieve this?  I have a JS fiddle setup here: http://jsfiddle.net/fZpzT/ but the code looks like this.  Thanks.

```
function addListItems() {
var str = {
    listitem1:'personal background check',
    listitem2:'look into my sketchy neighbor',
    listitem3:'look up my driving record',
    listitem4:'pick up milk',
    listitem5:'wash the car'
}

$('.list-container li').each(function(){
    var z = $(this).attr('id');
    var str2 = str[z];
    var delay = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i <= str2.length; i++) {
        (function(str2){
            delay += 100 + Math.floor(Math.random()*11)*6;
            setTimeout(function(){
                appendStr(str2);       
            },delay);
        })(str2[i])
    }
    function appendStr(str2) {
      $('#'+ z).append(str2);
    }
});
}
```

Comment: +1 for a well written question and jsfiddle example. I'm not sure immediately what the *solution* to this is, but I'm pretty sure the problem is **not** `.each()`, but rather your use of `setTimeout()`. `setTimeout()` is executing asynchronously, meaning that the entire loop finishes iteratively (not simultaneously), but finishes *very quick*, and then the `setTimeout` function handlers get to work *after* the loop has finished.

Comment: I would be looking [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) for some ideas on how to chain these functions using `deferred`.

Comment: I agree with Snixtor's explanation and would add that you should probably multiply the delay value according to which list item you're on (you could use `each(function(index) {...` to get the index). No extra delay needed for the first item, but you could delay the second item by 1 second, the 3rd by 2 seconds, etc., which would give the effect of one list item added per second.

Comment: Using `defferred` as Aesthete suggested would probably be a cleaner solution.

Comment: If you want to use deferred, you will also need to add a trigger when the typing has finished. That is quite easily done, but you will probably end up having less understandable code in the end. I would suggest you wrap this into a plugin-like pattern nonetheless.

Comment: @Brian: Check my updated answer. I have fixed the defect from last time, rather doing `cumulativeDelay += delay;`, it should have been `cumulativeDelay = delay;`. Hope this is more like what you wanted...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about simplifying? Use two variables to iterate the entire contents of a slightly modified data structure in a single loop. Like this. http://jsfiddle.net/cXykd/

```
var strings = 
[
    { "id":"listitem1", "text": "write the first item" },
    { "id":"listitem2", "text": "write the second item" },
    { "id":"listitem3", "text": "write the third item" },
    { "id":"listitem4", "text": "write the fourth item" },
    { "id":"listitem5", "text": "write the fifth item" },
 ]

var stringsIndex = 0;
var textIndex = 0;

AddString();

function AddString(){
    if (stringsIndex < strings.length){
        if (textIndex >= strings[stringsIndex].text.length)
        {
            stringsIndex++;
            if (stringsIndex == strings.length)
            {
                return;
            }
            textIndex = 0;
        }

        $("#" + strings[stringsIndex].id).append(strings[stringsIndex].text[textIndex]);
        textIndex++;

        var delay = 10 + Math.floor(Math.random()*11)*6;
        setTimeout(AddString, delay);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Snixtor.  I ended up going with this solution because it was the easiest for me to understand as I had to add a callback after the entire thing was done and some additional functionality after each iteration through the strings.

Answer (score 4):

Make the delay cumulative: [Demo on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FloydPink/eLPhg/4/)

```
var str = {
    listitem1: 'write the first item',
    listitem2: 'write the second item',
    listitem3: 'write the third item',
    listitem4: 'write the fourth item',
    listitem5: 'write the fifth item'
}, cumulativeDelay = 0;

$('.list-container li').each(function () {
    var z = $(this).attr('id');
    var str2 = str[z];
    var delay = cumulativeDelay;
    for (var i = 0; i <= str2.length; i++) {
        (function (str2) {
            delay += 100 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 11) * 6;
            setTimeout(function () {
                appendStr(str2);
            }, delay);
        })(str2[i])
    }
    cumulativeDelay = delay;
    function appendStr(str2) {
        $('#' + z).append(str2);
    }
    $(this).css('color', 'red');
});
```

Comment: no need for the extra variable.  Can simply move the line `var delay = 0;` outside of the `each` to achieve the same result.

Comment: Thanks Floyd.  I went with Snixtor's solution because I liked it better then my original one but thumbs up for finding a solution using my existing code.

Answer (score 3):

I would reverse the workings:

1. You start with the strings you want to write,
2. For each string:

   1. Find the corresponding list item (by id)
   2. Write the whole string in typewriter style
   3. Invoke the next iteration when done.

      ```
      var strings = [
        'personal background check',
        'look into my sketchy neighbor',
        'look up my driving record',
        'pick up milk',
        'wash the car'
      ];

      function iterate(strings, idx)
      {
        if (idx >= strings.length) { return; }

        var id = 'listitem' + (idx + 1),
        el = document.getElementById(id);

        typewriter(el, strings[idx], 0, function() {
          iterate(strings, idx + 1);
        });
      }

      function typewriter(el, str, idx, cb)
      {
        if (idx >= str.length) {
          return cb();
        }

        setTimeout(function() {
          el.innerText = str.substr(0, idx + 1);
          typewriter(el, str, idx + 1, cb);
        }, 100 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 11) * 6);
      }
      ```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/egayah/1/)

Comment: Thank you Jack.  I ended up going with Snixtor's solution but your take on it was excellent as well.